# Repeat a string N times and declare as a variable

Tags: php, string, loops, repeat

If I have a simple code like this:

```
$a = "hi";

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    echo $a;
}
```

so the output will be `hihihi` , is it possible to convert it into a string such as `$b="hihihi"` without through the loop anymore?
I'm using it for other function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that your situation is a little more complicated than the example given...

One option would be to not echo your variables to the buffer. Instead, append them to your own variable:

```
$out = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    $out .= 'hi';
}

echo $out; // "hihihi"
```

However, if, for whatever reason the echoing is not happening in code that you have control over, you could use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

```
ob_start();
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    doSomethingWhichPrintsHi();
}
$out = ob_get_clean();  // "hihihi"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str_repeat($str, $count)` to achieve this:

```
$str = str_repeat("hi", 3);
echo $str;
```

The above code will print "hihihi".

Here's the documentation for it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

Answer (score 1):

There are options without a loop:

```
$b = str_repeat('hi', 3); // hihihi
```

or, if you have an array:

```
$array = array ( 'hi', 'bye', '!!!' );
$b = implode('', $array); // hibye!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_repeat(string $input, int $multiplier)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php).

```
$b = str_repeat($a, 3);
```

Also see my [example](http://ideone.com/o04DV).

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
function stringdoubler($string, $duplicates) {
  if ($duplicates > 1)
    $string = $string . stringdoubler($string, $duplicates-1);
  return $string;
}

echo stringdoubler("hi",3);

?>
```

Comment: A recursive function for that kind of problem? Are you serious?

Comment: This twisted madness is being printed out and put on my "wall of overengineering".

Comment: Recursion isn't complicated :)